# HTML CSS fullscreen background with an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullscreen

I'm working on a website which uses a fullscreen background image. And in order
to make it work on all screen types I'm using jquery backstretch plugin.

The problem I have is the background image has some text on it and if the screen size gets smaller, the image on the background and the image on top overlays each other.

It's rather difficult to explain so here is the actual page;

[preview page](http://alicantest.info/EN/contact)

if the width of the page goes down below 1700 pixels you'll see the problem.

Is there any way to solve this problem without separating the text from the background?

Comment: The background is working fine. The only issue is the choice of background conflicts with your content.

Comment: Yes I know, but is there any other way you could think of to solve this issue.

Comment: use a different background for small screen sizes?

Comment: What exactly are your constraints?

Comment: If I manage to separate the chalk writing from the background I could easily make it work, but in this case I can't think of another way. Using different images for different screen sizes might work, but I'm looking for a more reliable and easy solution.

Comment: Building sites mobile first is best practice as more people will access via their handheld instead of a large screen. Your website is nice but the background text makes it impossible to read on my phone. I would rethink the background. Best of luck =)

Answer (score 4):

you can use **background-size: cover;**

```
{
      background: url(http://alicantest.info/public/_images/anasayfa_bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
}
```

or use an other image in media query

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1700px) {

    {
          background: url(newImage.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    }

}
```

Comment: The background itself works fine. Please look at the example. The problem is it conflicts with the content on top of it. What I'm asking is, is there any other approach you could think of to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a semi transparent background to the text when the screen is smaller with a media query

```
@media screen and (max-width: 795px){
    #map_text {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    }
}
```

Put this code at the bottom of your CSS